# How to remove a filename from bash completion, based on its suffix?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I'm (unsuccessfully) trying to edit the bash completion options for `vim`.

Specifically, when editing a LaTeX document, there are lots of supplementary files which I don't want to edit with `vim`. i.e. I only want to edit `.tex` files, not `.aux`,  `.pdf` and other files that are generated when compiling a document.

I've played around with the `complete` command, but am not having much joy..

Why does the following command not remove `.aux` files from the list of generated file names?

```
$ complete -o default -X '^.*aux' vim
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you want is not a regex, it is a `bash` glob and you need the `-f` to tell it you are completing files. Also you don't want `default` for `-o` since this will add in the filenames you just filtered out, either drop the option or choose something different (I have used `dirnames` so that it also completes directories). The following should do the job:

```
complete -f -o dirnames -X '*.@(aux|pdf)' vim
```

The relevant `man` page quote for the glob used:

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the following description, a
>          pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> ```
>           ?(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>           *(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           +(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           @(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one of the given patterns
>           !(pattern-list)
>                  Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

`extglob` should already be enabled by `bash` completion, but if not you need to do this also.